# Can we simplify this summation?

Tags: summation

Is it possible to simplify the following expression in a form without the sum?
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(e^x)^i(e^y)^{i^2}$$
equivalent to 
$$\sum_{i=0}^na^ib^{i^2}$$
where $a=e^x, b=e^y$
If it's not possible, is it nevertheless possible to do so if we take the limit $n\to\infty$ or if we put some constraints on $x$ and $y$?

I've tried rewriting it as a simpler sum first, but couldn't come up with anything.

---

**Edit: so there is no closed form solution. Does this change when we let $a=1$, so that the summation simply becomes the following?**
$$\sum_{i=0}^nb^{i^2}$$

Comment: Thinking that even the infinite sum $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} a^i b^{i^2}$ has no known closed form (hence is given a special name [*theta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)), I am skeptical about it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the [Jacobi Theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), we have

$$\vartheta_3\left(\ln\left(\frac a{2\pi i}\right),b\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^nb^{n^2}$$

for appropriate branches of the natural logarithm.  No closed forms are known about these functions in general, though now you've got a name you can append to these sorts of sums where the exponent involves $n^2$, which should allow you to research more specific identities and values more easily.

Comment: What if we let $a=1$? Do we then obtain a closed form solution?

Comment: @Programmer2134 Sadly no lol.  However, as seen in the link, there are a few known values.